# How to setup testthat for R CMD check?

Tags: r, testthat

There are apparently two ways to integrate `testthat` with `R CMD check`. I can't get either to work.

### Approach #1: (perhaps deprecated)

According to the [devtools wiki](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Testing#r-cmd-check):

> When developing a package, put your tests in inst/tests and then
>   create a file tests/run-all.R (note that it must be a capital R),
>   which contains the following code:

```
library(testthat) 
library(mypackage)
test_package("mypackage")
```

> This will evaluate your tests in the package
>   namespace (so you can test non-exported functions), and it will throw
>   an error if there are any test failures. This means you'll see the
>   full report of test failures and R CMD check won't pass unless all
>   tests pass.

The whole package is [here](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~nmv/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/minimalbugexample_0.1.1.tar.gz). In it are the two files:

```
## minimalbugexample/inst/tests/run-all.R
library(testthat)
library(minimalbugexample)
test_package('minimalbugexample')
```

and

```
## minimalbugexample/inst/tests/test-use-Matrix-package.R
context("Intentional break")
  expect_that( TRUE, equals(FALSE))
```

my DESCRIPTION is

```
Package: minimalbugexample
Title: 
Description: 
Version: 0.1.1
Author: Nathan VanHoudnos <nathanvan@letterafterFmail.com>
Maintainer: Nathan VanHoudnos <nathanvan@letterafterFmail.com>
Depends:
    R (>= 3.0.1),
    Matrix (>= 1.0)
Suggests:
    testthat
License: GPL
LazyData: true
Collate:
    'minimalbugexample-package.r'
    'use-Matrix-package.R'
```

After installing the package, I can run the tests just fine (they fail, as expected).

```
> test_package('minimalbugexample')
Intentional break : 1


1. Failure:  -------------------------------------------------------------------
TRUE not equal to FALSE
1 element mismatch
Error: Test failures
>
```

But an `R CMD check` doesn't run the tests.

```
$ R CMD check minimalbugexample_0.1.1.tar.gz 
... snip ...
* checking PDF version of manual ... WARNING
WARNING: There was 1 warning.
See
  ‘/home/nathanvan/software/minimalbugexample.Rcheck/00check.log’
for details.
```

I don't think that the PDF warning has anything to do with this, but I can provide more details if requested.

### Approach #2: (bleeding edge)

According to the [README file of the `testthat` repository](https://github.com/hadley/testthat#integration-with-r-cmd-check):

> Now, recommend practice is to put your tests in tests/testthat, and
>   ensure R CMD check runs then by putting the following code in
>   tests/test-all.R:

```
library(testthat)
test_check(yourpackage)
```

So I made sure I had the most recent version of testthat installed:

```
> install_github("testthat")
```

And then changed the package. You can get this version [here](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~nmv/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/minimalbugexample_0.1.2.tar.gz). I modified the two files to be

```
## minimalbugexample/inst/tests/test-all.R
library(testthat)
test_check(minimalbugexample)
```

and

```
## minimalbugexample/inst/tests/testthat/test-use-Matrix-package.R
context("Intentional break")
  expect_that( TRUE, equals(FALSE))
```

Then updating the package version to 0.1.2 in the DESCRIPTION file, I can build it, install it, and use `testthat` to check it and get the same output as before. So it seems that as far as `testthat` is concerned, its working.

However, R CMD check still doesn't run the tests:

```
$ R CMD check minimalbugexample_0.1.2.tar.gz 
... snip ...
* checking PDF version of manual ... WARNING
LaTeX errors when creating PDF version.
This typically indicates Rd problems.
WARNING: There was 1 warning.
See
  ‘/home/nathanvan/software/minimalbugexample.Rcheck/00check.log’
for details.
```

### So the question:

What am I doing wrong? My preference is for a solution for Approach 2, but I'll take either!

Comment: Just a note that if you're using approach #1 you [need to add](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21380288/loading-the-testthat-package-only-for-tests-but-not-requiring-in-dependencies) testthat to `Suggests:` in `DESCRIPTION`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't have a `tests` directory.  `test-all.R` should be located at `minimalbugexample/tests/test-all.R`.

Then your actual tests go in `minimalbugexample/inst/tests` for approach #1 or `minimalbugexample/tests/testthat/` for approach #2.

For approach #2, the `test-all.R` file should use `test_check(yourpackage)` instead of `test_package(yourpackage)` and the `library(yourpackage)` call is no longer required.

Comment: I guess the issue is that I can't read! Thanks! (Works for Approach #2!)

Comment: Actually, for approach #2, the `test-all.R` file should be located at `minimalbugexample/tests/test-all.R` as you say, but the actual tests go in `minimalbugexample/tests/testthat/`. It took some more bug testing for me to work it out. If you incorporate that into your answer I'll re-accept it! [Example on gitHub](https://github.com/nathanvan/minimalbugexample/tree/e6d62a6da7127fc165332935db04aa88b4575ae6).

Comment: Thanks. Editing is a new priv for me, so I was unsure of the community norms.

Comment: Also, to avoid a warning about unspecified dependencies, you should add `Suggests: testthat` to your DESCRIPTION file

Comment: Running the tests is amongst the last actions of `R CMD check <pkg>`, so any errors that occur earlier could prevent them from running.  Such as the lack of a `NAMESPACE` file.

Comment: Also note that the *uppercase* extension to `test-all.R` is essential. Otherwise `R CMD check` won't run the tests.