# Loading the testthat package only for tests but not requiring in dependencies

Tags: r, dependencies, package

Building a package results in the following warning:

```
* checking for unstated dependencies in tests ... WARNING
‘library’ or ‘require’ call not declared from: ‘testthat’
* checking tests ...
  Running ‘test-all.R’
 OK
* checking PDF version of manual ... OK
WARNING: There was 1 warning.
```

The package directory has a folder called `tests`, with a file test-all.R:

```
library(testthat)
library(bootLR)

test_package("bootLR")
```

Then a subfolder `testthat` with two files in it that hold the various tests.

The error message is likely telling me that I have not declared testthat in the DESCRIPTION file, but I don't want to require its installation by end-users, and I believe that putting the `library(testthat)` statement in the test-all.R file comes from the testthat manual.

Any way around this, or do I have to add it in the proper way (that forces uses to install testthat)?

Edit: I guess adding it to `Suggests:` might be the best way to do this?

Comment: I was slowing coming to that conclusion.  That did it, at least until test_check() is [implemented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595796/how-to-setup-testthat-for-r-cmd-check).  Thanks.  Re-post as an answer and I'll mark it answered?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe suggests? As [per Hadley](https://github.com/hadley/testthat/issues/103).